# Estoy tratando de mostrar un valor de -3, si un usuario intenta hacer una reserva y esto hace que tenga 3 reservas en columnas(franjas) continuas

Tags: java

Esta la matriz de usuarios con la cual estoy trabajando, la matriz cuenta con unos usuarios ya establecidos y con espacios vacíos

```
String[][] matrizNombres =
            //  0           1          2          3          4          5          6
{ 
    { "ttellez", "     "  , "      " , "      " , "      " , "      " , "vvaca"  }, //0
    { "vvaca"  , "     "  , "vvaca"  , "xxiang" , "ttellez", "uusa"   , "      " }, //1
    { "uusa"   , "     "  , "ttellez", "      " , "      " , "      " , "      " }, //2
    { "     "  , "jjaimes", "aavilla", "ggil"   , "jjaimes", "ppina"  , "      " }, //3
    { "ggil"   , "eenciso", "      " , "rroa"   , "lluna"  , "      " , "ggil"   }, //4
    { "fforero", "lluna"  , "mmarin" , "      " , "rroa"   , "mmarin" , "      " }, //5
    { "aavila" , "bbernal", "      " , "ccasas" , "      " , "      " , "dduran" }, //6
    { "dduran" , "fforero", "eenciso", "      " , "      " , "ssosa"  , "      " }, //7
    { "      " , "      " , "nnino"  , "bbernal", "nnino"  , "      " , "jjaimes"}, //8
    { "iibia"  , "hholmes", "      " , "ssosa"  , "iibia"  , "oostos" , "ccasas" }, //9
    { "kkant"  , "      " , "      " , "      " , "bbernal", "qquall" , "kkant"  }, //10
    { "lluna"  , "ccasas" , "iibia"  , "      " , "kkant"  , "      " , "oostos" }, //11
    { "ccasas" , "      " , "qquall" , "      " , "      " , "hholmes", "bbernal"}, //12
    { "      " , "      " , "      " , "zzidane", "      " , "      " , "      " }, //13
    { "wwells" , "zzidane","wwells"  , "      " , "xxiang" , "wwells" , "      " }, //14
    { "      " , "uusa"   , "      " , "      " , "      " , "zzidane", "iibia"  }, //15
    { "yyepez" , "      " , "oostos" ,"      "  , "mmarin" , "      " , "      " }, //16
    { "      " , "xxiang" , "yyepez" , "ppina"  , "      " , "      " , "zzidane"}, //17
    { "      " , "      " , "      " , "      " , "yyepez" , "      " , "      " }, //18
    { "xxiang" , "      " , "      " , "      " , "      " , "      " , "yyepez" }  //19
};
```

Aquí estamos llamando el método, el -5 y -4 son de otra funciones implementadas

```
String nombre = "eenciso";
byte sala = 16;
byte franja = 3;

int resultado = intentar_reserva(matrizNombres, nombre, sala, franja);
    
if (resultado == -5) {
    System.out.println("-5");
}
if (resultado == -4) {
    System.out.println("-4");
}
if (resultado == -3) {
    System.out.println("-3");
        
}
```

Debo respetar este encabezado de método

```
/* Si el usuario está intentando hacer una reserva de una sala para una franja que 
resultaría en tener tres franjas continuas asignadas, sin importar si es la misma sala 
o son salas diferentes, el método debería devolver un valor de tres negativo (-3).*/
static int intentar_reserva(String[][] salas, String usuario, byte sala, byte franja)
```

Es aquí donde se implementa el recorrido por la matriz

```
static int intentar_reserva(String[][] salas, String usuario, byte sala, byte franja) {
   // El usuario está intentando hacer una reserva que resultaría en tres franjas continuas
   int franjasContiguas = 0;
   for (int i = franja + 1; i <= franja ; i++) {
       if (salas[sala][i] != null && salas[sala][i].equals(usuario)) {
            franjasContiguas++;
            if (franjasContiguas >= 3) {
                return -3;           
            }
        }       
    }

    return 2;
}
```

Esto es todo un proyecto mucho más grande, pero al momento de validar si el usuario ingresado está tratando de hacer una reserva en una franja(columna) que resultaría en tres franjas continuas, el programa no me devuelve nada, debería retornar un -3. Tengo limitaciones para resolver este problema: no puedo usar break o clases que ya existan para resolverlo.

Answer (score 0):

Los términos franjas y salas son algo confusos, no me queda claro cuales son las filas y cuales las columnas de tu matriz, así que he usado directamente esos identificadores: fila y columna.

Yo empezaría definiendo una serie de constantes que nos servirán para establecer los límites de nuestra búsqueda, así como los códigos de resultados.

```
private static final int RES_CONTIGUAS = -3;
private static final int RES_OK = 2;
private static final byte MIN_COLUMNAS = 0;
private static final byte MAX_COLUMNAS = 6;
private static final byte MIN_FILAS = 0;
private static final byte MAX_FILAS = 19;
```

Mi método main sería

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String nombre = "eenciso";
    byte fila = 16;
    byte columna = 3;

    int resultado = intentarReserva(matrizNombres, nombre, fila, columna);

    System.out.println(resultado);
}
```

Un apunte, ¿porque no escribes directamente el resultado en lugar de tener tantos bloques if? No necesitas poner la cadena que representa a cada entero. Al invocar a System.out.println, java ya va a llamar al toString de los enteros y para el entero -5 te va a escribir "-5", y lo mismo para cualquier entero.

Para verificar la reserva, la implementación sería

```
private static int intentarReserva(String[][] salas, String usuario, byte fila, byte columna) {
    checkLimits(fila, columna);

    salas[fila][columna] = usuario;

    return (checkFila(salas, usuario, fila, columna) || checkColumna(salas, usuario, fila, columna)) ? RES_CONTIGUAS : RES_OK;
}
```

Lo primero que he añadido es un método que me valide si las posiciones deseadas se encuentran dentro de mi matriz. En caso de que no lo estén se lanza una excepción.

```
  private static void checkLimits(byte fila, byte columna) {
    boolean dentroLimites =
            (fila >= MIN_FILAS) && (fila <= MAX_FILAS) 
         && (columna >= MIN_COLUMNAS) && (columna <= MAX_COLUMNAS);

    if (!dentroLimites) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Búsqueda fuera de los límites permitidos");
    }
}
```

A continuación establezco el nombre en la posición de la matriz, porque debemos comprobar si hay tres nombres iguales contiguos pero ocupando la posición de entrada, como si esa persona ya estuviera sentada.

Para finalizar he dividido el problema en dos, si tenemos tres posiciones contiguas en la fila seleccionada o si tenemos tres posiciones contiguas en la columna seleccionada.

No te incluyo el código de los métodos checkXXXX porque es lo que tienes que hacer tú y más o menos parecías encaminado. Lo que yo he pensado para averiguar si se daban tres contiguos es examinar dos posiciones por delante de la que se da de entrada y dos por detrás. Y comprobar si en ese intervalo hay tres contiguos iguales.

Es decir, en tu ejemplo que se selecciona sala=16, franja=3 [fila=16, columna=3], para ver si hay contiguos en esa **fila**, miraría las columnas

```
 { "yyepez" , "******" , "******" ,"******", "******" , "******", "      " }
```

que son 1 y 2 por detrás, y 4 y 5 por delante, de la 1 a la 5. O lo que es lo mismo de (3 - 2) a (3 + 2). Recordemos que 3 es la columna seleccionada. Esto vale para cualquier columna, esos deberían ser los valores empleados en tu for, teniendo en cuenta que la posición de inicio no puede ser menor que 0 y la posición final no puede ser mayor que 6.

Para ver si hay contiguos en esa **columna**, miraría las siguientes posiciones

```
{ "wwells" , "zzidane","wwells"  , "******" , "xxiang" , "wwells" , "      " }, //14
{ "      " , "uusa"   , "      " , "******" , "      " , "zzidane", "iibia"  }, //15
{ "yyepez" , "      " , "oostos" , "******"  , "mmarin" , "      " , "      " }, //16
{ "      " , "xxiang" , "yyepez" , "******"  , "      " , "      " , "zzidane"}, //17
{ "      " , "      " , "      " , "******" , "yyepez" , "      " , "      " }, //18
{ "xxiang" , "      " , "      " , "      " , "yyepez" , "      " , "yyepez" }  //19
```

Es decir para ver si hay contiguos en esa columna, miraría las filas 14, 15, 16, 17 y 18. O lo que es lo mismo de (16 - 2) a (16 + 2). Estos deberían ser los límites de tu for, teniendo en cuenta lo mismo que te comentaba antes, el límite inferior no puede ser menor que 0 y el superior no puede ser mayor que 19.